# What is the best way to deal with this Namespace JavaScript Structure?

Tags: javascript, architecture

i have an object as namespace with three main-objects. I call this object one time and after this it is working for itself.

My Code is structured like this:

```
var Application = Application || {};
Application.Module1 = {
//Code with some functions
}

Application.Module2 = {
   //Code with some functions
}

Application.Module3 = {
   //Code with some functions
}

(function(){
    Application.Module1.Start();
})();
```

Primarily the modules working among themselves. I would like to call for example when i'm in Module1 a function in Module2 like:

```
Module2.randomFunction();
```

and not:

```
Application.Module2.randomFunction();
```

But i think it is a bad idea to go

```
Application.Module1.Start.call(Application)
```

because i'm using also other objects like jQuery.

What do you think would be the right way?

Comment: Perhaps you can do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/v60h6vfd/ . Not the best solution, but it's a Shorthand if you have to call some Module2 functions many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a pattern like this -

```
var Application = (function() {
    var Module1 = {
        function1 : function() {
            console.log("function1");
            Module2.function2();
        }
    };

    var Module2 = {
        function2 : function() {
            console.log("function2");
        }
    };

    var Module3 = {
        function3 : function() {
            console.log("function3");
        }
    };

    return {
        Module1: Module1,
        Module2: Module2,
        Module3: Module3
    }
})();

Application.Module1.function1();
```

Comment: Avoid capitalizing non constructor functions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! That looks like a pattern i was looking for! @BenAston what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @sibe94 By convention variables only start with a capital letter if they correspond to a constructor function or a constant.

Comment: Ah ok thank you! @jaibatrik has this pattern a name? I was searching for a documentation.

Comment: Not that I know of. This is kind of leveraging the closure virtue of JS to accomplish the namespace organization you want to achieve. JS is a very versatile language where you get complete control over the construct / pattern you want to follow.